# Java Interface<?> is equivalent to Interface<any> in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying "translate" some a java library to typescript.

```
public interface Expression<T> {
    <R,C> R accept(Visitor<R,C> v, @Nullable C context);
}
public interface Constant<T> extends Expression<T> {
    T getConstant();
}
public interface Visitor<R,C> {
    R visit(Constant<?> expr, @Nullable C context);
}
```

Up to now, I've been able to code this code:

```
interface Expression<T> {
    accept<R, C>(visitor: Visitor<R, C>, context: C) : R;
}
interface Constant<T> extends Expression<T> {
    () : T;
}
public interface Visitor<R,C> {
    (expr: Constant<any>, context: C): R;   //<<<<?>>>>
}
```

I'm not sure how to translate java `Constant<?>`. Up to now, I've translated it as `Constant<any>`.

Is this correct?

**[EDIT]**

What about `Interface<? super T>` and `Interface<? extends T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because generic parameter for Constant, `T`, does not appear anywhere in the `Visitor` interface definition, I'd guess nothing is known and nothing is needed - no methods, no properties - from that type. In this case, empty object type `{}` will suffice - it's assignable from almost any other type.

```
interface Expression<T> {
    accept<R, C>(visitor: Visitor<R, C>, context: C) : R;
}
interface Constant<T> extends Expression<T> {
    () : T;
}
interface Visitor<R,C> {
  (expr: Constant<{}>, context: C): R;   
}
```

**update**

Similar to java, TypeScript supports [generic type parameter constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints). It's hard to invent a realistic, but simple example where constraints are really necessary, so here is silly made up example:

```
interface Writer {
    write(data: string): void;
}

interface WriterProvider<W extends Writer> {
    getWriter(): W;
}

class C<W extends Writer> {

    writer: W; 

    constructor(writerProvider: WriterProvider<W>) {
        this.writer = writerProvider.getWriter();
    }

    writeAll(): void {
        this.writer.write('a'); // here we can use its write() method
    }

    // supposedly something here should take advantage 
    // of knowing exact W type, as opposed to Writer, at compile time
}
```

However, unlike java, typescript does not have wildcard generic parameters - there is no equivalent for `Interface<? super T>` and `Interface<? extends T>`. There is no way to translate such code directly to TypeScript - you have to use TypeScript idioms and figure out what's the best way to express what you need on case by case basis.

Java generic FAQ says that wildcards [are necessary in situations where no or only partial knowledge about the type argument of a parameterized type is required](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#What%20is%20a%20wildcard?).

[TypeScript has structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html). It means that as soon as there is any knowledge about the properties or methods of a type, you can use it right away where this knowledge is sufficient. In practice, there is no need to declare to the compiler that concrete type you are passing as actual generic parameter conforms to some interface or constraint - it comes naturally with structural types and the compiler is able to figure it out by itself.

Comment: Thanks @artem. I've edited the post. Could you provide me some lights about how to "translate" `<? super T>` and `<? extends T>`?